# Probability of being dealt two cards of given ranks from the same suit in a 13 card hand?

Tags: probability

A 13 card hand is randomly-drawn from a standard playing card deck. What is the probability that a 3 and 6 of the same suit is in the 13 card hand? What is the probability that all four suits of some rank are in the 13 card hand?

For the first part of the question, my reasoning was that we are interested in choosing two ranks of the same suit among the 13 possible, and given the four suits the probability should be

$$\frac{{13 \choose 2}{4 \choose 1}}{52 \choose 13}$$

but this gives an estimate in the order of $10^{-10}$, which seems unreasonably low.

Comment: you still have 11 more cards to select

Comment: @WW1 thanks for pointing that out. However, if I multiply the above by $52 \choose 11$ I get a probability greater than 1.

Comment: The thing is, you shouldn't really have $\binom {13}2$ in there, there are only 4 ways to have a 2 and a 6 of the same suit. When you get rid of that, you will be close, but to be perfect, you will need to deal with cases where you have both 2 and 6 of more than one suit.

Comment: @WW1 as suggested, I now choose 1 of the 4 suits, then have only one way of choosing the required way, and then choose the remaining 11 cards, which gives $\frac{{4 \choose 1}{52 \choose 11}{52 \choose 13} = \frac{78}{205} = 38%$. For the cases of 1, 2, 3, and 4 "pairs" in the 13 card hand combined it is ~45.5%.

Answer (score 1):

There are $4$ suits from which the $3$ and $6$ can come, and then you have $50$ cards from which to choose the remaining $11$.  That gives $4{50\choose11}$.  However, any hand containing both $3$ and $6$ of two different suits has been counted twice, so we need to subtract ${4\choose2}{48\choose9}$.  But now hands containing the $3$ and $6$ of three different suits have been added in three times (once fo each suit) and subtracted out three times (once for each pair of suits) so we have to add back in ${4\choose3}{46\choose7}$.  Finally hands with the $3$ and $6$ of each suit have been counted a net two times (check this), so we have to subtract ${44\choose5}.$

The probability is $$ 
{4{50\choose11}-{4\choose2}{48\choose9}+{4\choose3}{46\choose7}-{44\choose5}\over{52\choose13}}\approx21.978\%$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to clarify, does that give the probability of of having exactly one pair of 3 and 6, or at least one pair of 3 and 6?

Comment: @Daphne At least one.

Comment: Thank you. I assume that for the second part of the question I should take card of the repetitions by again applying the inclusion exclusion principle, with $13 \choose i$, but this time that becomes limited by the size of the hand. I would also be left with one more card. Could you lend me a hint as to how to solve that?

Comment: It's the same idea.  You have $13$ possible ranks, and if you have all the cards of one of them, then you must choose $9$ cards from the remaining $48$.  But then hands which have all the cards of two ranks have been counted twice, so you have to subtract them.  Then hands with all cards of $3$ ranks haven't been counted at all, so add them in.  You can't have all the cards of $4$ ranks, so it stops there.